# VScode stops working with ElixirLS plugin, and system freezes. LinuxMint machine

Tags: elixir, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

**Prior Question**: How to setpath for system wide use of Elixir and configuring VScode for ElixirLS?
**Question Updated**

I installed Elixir using this tutorial on my Linuxmint machine.  https://gist.github.com/emerleite/6d44f64d2a5b6be933c0b533234f1c88

> **Solved**:
>   But I have to each time run at my shell $. .bash_profile to fire up
>   exenv to load the elixir. How to make it system wide or set path so
>   that I can just fire iex without each time calling the at shell $.
>   .bash_profile.

When I open VSCode, with Elixir-Ls https://github.com/JakeBecker/vscode-elixir-ls plugin installed, my system just freezes. And I can't click anything. VSCode shows a pop up message as

> "Failed to run "elixir" command ElixirLs will probably fail to launch

"
Kindly help how to get ElixirLs working fine for Visual Studio. I even tried with "asdf" but didn't work for Vscode.

Comment: Did you install `elixir` correctly and can you run `elixir` command in your command line? Seems that this extension just can't find `elixir` in your path. Try editing your `~.profile` instead of `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @xji I am unable to open iex or use elixir command to run it. I have to do this.

' ~ $ elixir
The program 'elixir' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install elixir
 ~ $ . .bash_profile 
 ~ $ iex
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source-e7be63d] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> 
'

Without giving, $ . . bash_profile I'm unable to start

Comment: If you're using bash, I don't understand why you can access it by reloading `.bash_profile` but not directly in `bash`. In any case. Try what I said, add what you added in `~/.bash_profile` into your `~/.profile` not your `~/.bash_profile`, and restart the system to see if it worked.

Comment: @xji https://pastebin.com/SwwCFHWg here is the whole profile, bashrc, bash_profile setups and how I'm actually having this issue

Comment: @xji I gave  below across all the profile, bashrc, bash_profile. Now it's actually working. But hopefully if face issue I will trouble again. Now have to work on the ElixirLS issue. Thanks for the direction in a way

export PATH="$HOME/.exenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(exenv init -)"

Comment: Good to see that it worked. You could accept my answer below to mark this question as solved. This bug is caused by your environment variable setup. If you encounter further bugs with ElixirLS you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the environment variables in `.bash_profile` will only let the path be picked up by the bash shell. If you want all your applications, including VSCode, to see such environment variables, you have to set it in your `.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you did will only work for git bash terminal and not for cmd or powershell.

If you are on Windows, go to this part "~/asdf/installs/elixir//bin". Copy the path and add it to your environment variable...